# Expect not waiting for prompt - script stops without sending other commands

Tags: expect

Before this is chalked up as a `timeout`, or `max_match` issue, I will say that I have tried those.  I have also tried using `full_buffer`, but it seems the only fix is to put a `sleep`after the`expect` when a large output comes before it.  It's almost as if the `expect ">$"` is seen and processed by expect before the terminal can print the output.

`term len 0` is a cisco command to basically prevent the default `| more` of the file

Example:

```
    set timeout -1
    spawn ssh host
    expect "assword:"
    send "$pass\r"
    expect ">$"
    send "term len 0\r"
    expect ">$"
    set size_orig [match_max]
    match_max 60000000
    send "show start\r"
    expect ">$"
```

does not work.  The output of "show start" is stopped x lines into the output.

If I put handling for `timeout` and `full_buffer`, the same thing happens:

```
    set timeout -1
    spawn ssh host
    expect "assword:"
    send "$pass\r"
    expect ">$"
    send "term len 0\r"
    expect ">$"
    set size_orig [match_max]
    match_max 60000000
    set timeout -1
    send "show start\r"
    expect {
           timeout {
                   send $expect_out(buffer)
           }
           full_buffer {
                   send $expect_out(buffer)
           }

           ">$" {
           append outcome $expect_out(buffer)
   }
   }
```

The only way I was able to fix this was adding a `sleep` after the `expect ">$"` (I did this in the simple script below, and also in the script which handles `full_buffer` and `timeout`) :

```
    set timeout -1
    spawn ssh host
    expect "assword:"
    send "$pass\r"
    expect ">$"
    send "term len 0\r"
    expect ">$"
    set size_orig [match_max]
    match_max 60000000
    set timeout -1
    send "show start\r"
    expect ">$"
    sleep 10
```

This works, but is there a proper way to do this as opposed to making the script wait by `sleep`ing?  Not all of the devices have such large outputs, so the sleep is not needed on each host.

one additional test I made was running the script with `expect -d` and the following was at the end of the truncated ouput:

```
tty_set: raw = 3, echo = 0
```

Thanks,
chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following resolved the issue in my script by suppressing the output displayed to the user, and rather, appending it to my `log_file` :

```
log_file -a initial_commands
log_user 0
send "some commands with large output"
log_file
log_user 1
```

In this case it does not matter whether the user sees the output, as I am parsing it and outputting it to a file anyway.  To further disprove it was an error in my `expect "<$"` code, I experienced this same behavior (by complete accident) when running `system "parse.pl"`.  That perl script simply read the large output of `show start` and printed it line by line.  Sure enough, the output stopped short and the script stopped.  If anyone would like to dive deeper into this issue, please let me know and I can gladly provide more info.